# How to find all unique combinations of k size tuple using a single element from each list of n lists

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list containing N sublists of multiple lengths, find all unique combinations of a k size, selecting only one element from each sublist.

- The order of the elements in the combination is not relevant: (a, b) = (b, a)

`sample_k = 2`

`sample_list = [['B1','B2','B3'], ['T1','T2'], ['L1','L2','L3','L4']]`

```
expected_output =
[
('B1', 'T1'),('B1', 'T2'),('B1', 'L1'),('B1', 'L2'),('B1', 'L3'),('B1', 'L4'),
('B2', 'T1'),('B2', 'T2'),('B2', 'L1'),('B2', 'L2'),('B2', 'L3'),('B2', 'L4'),
('B3', 'T1'),('B3', 'T2'),('B3', 'L1'),('B3', 'L2'),('B3', 'L3'),('B3', 'L4'),
('T1', 'L1'),('T1', 'L2'),('T1', 'L3'),('T1', 'L4'),
('T2', 'L1'),('T2', 'L2'),('T2', 'L3'),('T2', 'L4')
]
```

- Extra points for a pythonic way of doing it
- Speed/Efficiency matters, the idea is to use in a list with hundreds of lists ranging from 5 to 50 in length

What I have been able to accomplish so far:
Using for and while loops to move pointers and build the answer, however I am having a hard time figuring out how to include K parameter to set the size of tuple combination dinamically. (not really happy about it)

```
def build_combinations(lst):
    result = []
    count_of_lst = len(lst)
    for i, sublist in enumerate(lst):
        if i == count_of_lst - 1:
            continue
        else:
            for item in sublist:
                j = 0
                while i < len(lst)-1:
                    while j <= len(lst[i+1])-1:
                        comb = (item, lst[i+1][j])
                        result.append(comb)
                        j = j + 1
                    i = i + 1
                    j = 0
                i = 0
    return result
```

I've seen many similar questions in stack overflow, but none of them addressed the parameters the way I am trying to (one item from each list, and the size of the combinations being a params of function)

I tried using itertools combinations, product, permutation and flipping them around without success. Whenever using itertools I have either a hard time using only one item from each list, or not being able to set the size of the tuple I need.

I tried NumPy using arrays and a more math/matrix approach, but didn't go too far. There's definitely a way of solving with NumPy, hence why I tagged numpy as well

Comment: Nice assignment. Have you made any progress in doing the work, or do you expect us to do it for you? What code have you written so far? Where are you stuck? Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Since you tagged numpy, Is the solution supposed to use numpy? .

Comment: @Grismar Sorry for the sloppy question, it was not my intention. I wrote down some more details, and a working func for a K = 2, but i'm not happy with it. looks like I am coding python in C

Comment: @Alexander I've edited the question with some details regards NumPy. I imagined that probably someone would be able to use arrays and matrix operations so solve this combinatory problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *combine* two `itertools` helpers, `combinations` to select the two unique ordered `list`s to use, then `product` to combine the elements of the two:

```
from itertools import combinations, product

sample_k = 2

sample_list = [['B1','B2','B3'], ['T1','T2'], ['L1','L2','L3','L4']]

expected_output = [pair
                   for lists in combinations(sample_list, sample_k)
                   for pair in product(*lists)]
print(expected_output)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY@7DoMwDEX3fIW3QJWl0LULM2M3FCEKQY1K4igxUvv1KaEP9aF6sHRt6fjYXemEtoxx9GhAk/KEOAXQxqEn6NEcte1Iow0CnMdh7omx0Bk3qfYMeyheadKBlkHT8GrLBa@K1EouBTT8kCaH4h7qFOq0rsvUdlxKxtTFqZ7U0OJMbl5JrtOewW@N6CFdWzTth2L2piLgaZn/YyR@Qjz@yjYrNJfMeW0p@zLKY7wB)

If you want to get *really* fancy/clever/ugly, you can push all the work down to the C layer with:

```
from itertools import combinations, product, starmap, chain

sample_k = 2

sample_list = [['B1','B2','B3'], ['T1','T2'], ['L1','L2','L3','L4']]

expected_output = list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(product, combinations(sample_list, sample_k))))
print(expected_output)
```

That will almost certainly run meaningfully faster for huge inputs (especially if you can loop the results from `chain.from_iterable` directly rather than realizing them as a `list`), but it's probably not worth the ugliness unless you're *really* tight for cycles (I wouldn't expect much more than a 10% speed-up, but you'd need to benchmark to be sure).

Comment: Nice, I've actually got to a similar solution using `itertools`. Using list comprehension though will not work for dynamically set different `k`parameter. ( increasing K requires lista, listb, listc,... Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: I've updated @ShadowRanger 's answer in response to your comment. You have to wonder if you really understand the solution if you couldn't make that change yourself though. The clever work here lies in the solution provided by them, adding on `sample_k` was trivial. I don't agree that the latter solution is "ugly" but it does fail on being "readable" for most developers, especially ones new to Python, and the use of `starmap()` is a bit of cleverness that most would have missed, so it's not exactly intuitive.

Comment: @eric_308: Ah, forgot that. Still works fine as a listcomp though, you just avoid unpacking to a fixed number of names, and unpack dynamically as positional arguments to the `product` call. Looks like Grismar already made that edit.

Comment: Unsure who voted down the answer - if they would care to provide a comment why they think this answer isn't good, that would be helpful?

Comment: @Grismar @ShadowRanger thanks for the help! I may be too tired looking at this, completely missed using `*args` in `product`. I'll try to `starmap` & `chain` as well and see how much faster does it get